# ANTLR. How to exclude double quotes from AST?

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

I have a following grammar and I would like to avoid " from being displayed as a node in AST. To do that I'm ! suffix, but ANTLWorks still shows'em on a tree. What an I doing wrong?

```
grammar BooleanExpr;

options {
output=AST;
    ASTLabelType=CommonTree; 
}

booleanExpr
    :   andExpr ('OR'^ andExpr)*;
andExpr :   kppExpr;
kppExpr :   keywordExpr | phraseExpr;
keywordExpr
    :CHAR+;
// exclude double quotes from AST
phraseExpr
    :   '"'! keywordExpr '"'!;

CHAR    :   ('A'..'Z') | ('a'..'z');
INT :   '0'..'9'+;
NEWLINE :   '\r'? '\n';
WS  :   (' '|'\t'|'\n'|'\r')+ {skip();};
```

Answer (score 1):

My bad, didn't switch view from "Parse Tree" to "AST". In "AST" view tree is built without double quotes.